# Formatting a tab-delimited CSV/TSV to force Excel to interpret value as a string

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, csv, string, text-formatting

I had a followup question to this related post -

[Formatting a CSV to force Excel to interpret value as a string (not date or number)](https://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string-not-date-or-numbe/318421#318421)

I was wondering how does one escape text starting with `"` using  *`"=""Data Here"""`* in a TAB delimited file..

Example:

```
 column1        column2        column3
 1              "SampleText    123465
```

I tried

```
"=""""SampleText"""
```

and

```
"="""SampleText"""
```

but neither worked!

Comment: Have you tried `\"`?

Answer (score 3):

It's ugly, but here's what we did. For other reasons, we basically export an text file containing a html table, and give it a .xls filename. We have data that needs to show (and export) as a fraction. To keep Excel from re-interpreting it as a decimal - or even worse, a date - we follow each fraction with a space and an html non-breaking space.

```
<td>7/12 &nbsp;</td>
```

This gets brought into Excel as a text string and shown as "7/12" as our customer wants.

I don't know if you could do something similar with a tab-delimited file, but I hope it's worth something to you.

Comment: Thanks @StevenV. But my problem is that a single **`"`** in the beginning of the text makes Excel interpret the rest of the data as one single cell. I can avoid this by using data import in Excel and asking the user to set the "Text qualifier" as none, but that would seem tedious to end user.